# How to make SQL server return only the exact matches?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sequelize.js, exact-match

I am using mssql database with sequelize for my node.js application. I want only the exact match of my query string.but I am getting the same strings with different cases also.

For example, I want to fetch the record where some column = 'work'. But if I give 'WoRK' or something like that it should not return anything. But it matches with the 'work' in the database.

How can I change that?

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server's string comparisons are by default case-insensitive (unless the table column is defined with a proper collation).

You can do this in the query by setting a `collation` for the equality - for example:

```
where some_column = 'work' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
```